# How do I use python findall to extract common part?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have an issue with re.findall

eg.

```
text = '[1]xxxxxxxx[2]xxxxxxxx[3]xxxxxx[4]xxxxxxxxxend'
re.findall('(\[\d{1,2}\].*?)(?:\[\d{1,2}\]|end)',text)
```

what I want is to extract `["[1]xxxxxxxx","[2]xxxxxxxx","[3]xxxxxx","[4]xxxxxxxxx"]`.

However when I did `re.findall('(\[\d{1,2}\].*?)(?:\[\d{1,2}\]|end)',text)`

I got `['[1]xxxxxxxx', '[3]xxxxxx']`

Any luck by this question

Comment: Use a lookahead insead of the non-capturing group, see https://regex101.com/r/I6HSyG/1

Answer (score 1):

The non-capturing group, `(?:...)`, does not create a separate memory buffer with the text matched, but it still *consumes* the text matched, i.e. it is added to the match value and the regex index is advanced.

You need a non-consuming pattern here, a positive lookahead:

```
re.findall(r'\[\d{1,2}\].*?(?=\[\d{1,2}\]|end)', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jHMy2Q/1).

The `(?=\[\d{1,2}\]|end)` pattern matches a ocation that is immediately followed with `[`, one or two digits and then `]`, or `end` char sequence.